# Why don't my ears pop in the morning going through a tunnel?

Tags: human-ear

I drive through a tunnel (morning and evening) on my normal work commute. In the evenings, my ears will pop going through this tunnel, but they do not pop in the mornings. There are actually 2 separate tunnels for the northbound and southbound traffic, but they are right next to each other, with the same elevation changes.

What is the difference as to why the ears only pop in 1 direction?

[Here's a short video of tunnel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Luh58qxZ-Kc)

Comment: Presumably the elevation change is in opposite directions.